# Singelton class does not work, multiple initialization on page reload

Tags: php, plugin-development

I would like to create a class that provides a logging mechanism. For this I have created the following class:

```
<?php
namespace tfaq;

final class Logger
{
    private static ?Logger $instance = null;
    private static $logfilePath;
    private static $writeCnt = 0;

    public static function getInstance(): Logger
    {
        if (static::$instance === null) {
            static::$instance = new static();

        static::$logfilePath = Init::getInstance()->get_plugin_path() . 'log.txt';

        if (!file_exists(static::$logfilePath)) {
            $log = fopen(static::$logfilePath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($log, '');
            fclose($log);
        }

        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    public function write_log_entry($text) {
        $log = fopen(static::$logfilePath, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

        if(static::$writeCnt>0) {
            fwrite($log, "\r\n");
        }

        fwrite($log, $text . '[ ' . static::$writeCnt . ' ]');
        fclose($log);

        static::$writeCnt = static::$writeCnt + 1;

    }

}
```

I use this class on one page:

```php
<?php

use tfaq\Logger;

Logger::getInstance()->write_log_entry('write log entry...');
```

If I reload this page several times now, I get the following file... I simply cannot explain it to myself. Maybe I am blind or stupid.

```
First Entry...[ 0 ]First Entry...[ 0 ]First Entry...[ 0 ]
```

Comment: This is a generic PHP question, and if you're wondering about the write counter which remained 0 in the log file, then it's because the counter always starts at 0 on each page load. I.e. The value persists only on the same request/page and be reset to zero on page (re)load.

Comment: Maybe the file containing `Logger::getInstance()->write_log_entry('write log entry...');` is being included / required several times?